# Parapharese "I will never get used to living in a village."

Tags: paraphrasing

```
I will never get used to living in a village.
```

paraphrasing this sentence? what ideas?
"get used to" the meaning and never synonym?

Comment: Are you able to look up the phrase *get used to*?

Comment: i think the meaning "get used to" refer to "get accustomed"

Answer (score 1):

I will not become accustomed to living in a village regardless of how long I live there.

Answer (score 0):

"I will never get used to living in a village."

One might say this if one is used to living in a city (or some other community larger than a village) but for some reason is now living in a village.

One might also say this if one is used to living in the country (or some community smaller than a village) but for some reason is now living in a village.

Either way, the person in question believes they will never be able to make the adjustments necessary to make living in a village feel comfortable or normal, that is, to make the adjustments necessary to "get used to" living in a village. The speaker is contrasting their comfort level in living in a village with their comfort level in living in other than a village.

Yet a third possibility is that the speaker has lived in a village their entire life, but for some reason feels they'll never be able to "get used to" it. I'd rule this out, because if the speaker has lived in a village their entire life, they have nothing to compare to that experience. It's not clear on what basis they could say they'll "never get used to" it.

Comment: The question should be C-Vd. And this comment should be unnecessary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Given that you feel that way, I assume you're one of the two people who's voted to close. That's your prerogative. Still, I don't consider that in and of itself  a valid reason for downvoting my answer, if you're the one who did it.

Comment: I find it unhelpful in that it encourages other answers to questions far from the standards ELU expects (ELL would probably flag this), in turn encouraging questions of similar standard and compromising the tone of the site. If people are to come here  expecting quality answers (these will almost always include linked references to accepted references), as I trust many do, site integrity must be maintained.

Comment: I find it ridiculous to downvote a good answer simply because the question isn't liked. A good answer is a good answer regardless. It's also helpful for the person who's asking the question, so +1 from me to offset this.

Comment: @JasonBassford Many thanks. Much appreciated. I couldn't agree more, as per the comment I just posted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure what you mean by ELU standards. If you applied your idiosyncratic personal standards to every question posted on ELU, there would be no questions and therefore no ELU. If you must, take issue with the questions (e.g., vote to close or migrate), not legitimate answers to those questions. In doing the latter, all you're doing is depriving the questioner of an answer, creating confusion regarding the quality of answers, and p***ing people off, none of which serve any useful purpose.

Comment: If you want a reason beyond the one I first gave why I consider this answer not up to ELU standards, _it lacks any (linked and attributed) authoritative references_.  It also goes beyond the remit of ELU, suggesting the thinking behind the writer's statement. ELU deals with the nuts and bolts of English; speculative interpretations belong on Literature.SE. And OP asks essentially for 'synonyms' rather than character studies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm torn. I can't decide whether there are more logical inconsistencies in, or questions raised by, this comment or your previous comment. I'm moving on.